# Passenger on Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, passenger

Is there any way to get Passenger running on a Windows machine?  It doesn't appear so, but it seems like many Stackoverflow'ers have used Passenger a lot and I was wondering if its *possible*.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Hongli (the author) [said in 2008](http://izumi.plan99.net/blog/index.php/2008/04/11/phusion-passenger-mod_rails-public-release-heck-it%E2%80%99s-about-time/):

> Hi Mitja. We have no plans to port
>   Passenger on Windows. Windows lacks
>   the proper facilities to implement
>   Passenger efficiently. Passenger on
>   Windows will be very, very
>   inefficient, which can give both Ruby
>   on Rails as well as Passenger a bad
>   name.

So to me it looks like your out of luck here. Just run a VM and do your Rails work on it. Ruby/Rails is painfully slow on windows. Simple things like Script/Console take upwards of 10 seconds (and only a second on a linux VM)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Helicon Zoo](http://www.helicontech.com/zoo/) instead.

Domus71