# How do I run Rails on Windows Server 2003 or 2008?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows

I developed a Rails application on Linux and it's about to launch, but my client's IT guys stopped it saying they want it to run on a Windows in-house server. I've never run a Rails application on Windows, but now I have to.

Questions:

- They will set up a dedicated Windows machine. Which is better, Windows Server 2003 or 2008?
- Do I use IIS web server? Is there any better option?
- I use Paperclip plugin with ImageMagick. What's the equivalent on Windows?

Do you any advice for me?

Comment: looks like you're in real trouble now. Have you checked that your database adapter works on windows? As far as IIS is concerned: I have not heard of anyone deploying a Rails app into that web server, sorry. Also, passenger is not available for win as this post suggests: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/999532/passenger-on-windows

Answer (score 2):

Running on Windows might be far from ideal, specially if your application used components that lack working version on Windows.

If is an application for intranet usage, you can deal running Thin standalone instead of putting things behind IIS. You will need to make your app work as service. For Rails 2.3 you have mongrel_service. For Rails 3 there is no service solution right now.

If you *require* to use IIS, please ask the IT guy to look at [Helicon Zoo](http://www.helicontech.com/zoo/)

There is ImageMagick for Windows, and works with Paperclip.

Comment: Yeah. I had to use mongrel + mongel_service with Rails 2.3. It was a headache but had no other option. I tried to update mongrel_service to work with Rails 3 but 1) didnt know BASIC 2) some cgi handlers were removed with Rails 3.

Comment: The issue with Rails 3 is more Mongrel than mongrel_service. I'm close to finish a newer wrapper that works with Rack or any command-line script. Will announce it soon.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is installing the application inside a Linux Virtual Machine above Windows Server, and treat it like an independent server in your network.