# Uploading RoR project to a webserver - Passenger error undefined method `dir' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger, web-deployment

My first test project to get online, so I'm not sure what I'm supposed to do. But I found a tutorial that I could upload my project with [Phusion Passenger](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/download). I followed the tutorial, but step 1 already fails.

If I type in the command `gem install passenger` I get the following error:

```
passenger-4.0.14/lib/phusion_passenger.rb:177:in `find_location_configuration_file': undefined method `dir' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.14/lib/phusion_passenger.rb:78:in `locate_directories'
    from extconf.rb:30:in `<main>'
```

Any idea what caused this or is there another way to get this project running on my own remote server?

Answer (score 5):

This error happens because you are running windows, passenger does not play well with windows, they offer no support, in part they say that Passenger on windows would be very inefficient and give a bad name to both Phusion Passenger and Ruby.

The full Answer can be read here [Passenger on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/999532/passenger-on-windows).

Hope it helps, if you still wanna develop on windows you can use a Virtual Machine, run linux on it and develop there, the feature Seamless of virtual box as example, runs linux apps as native windows apps (but installed on the linux virtual machine).

If you want you can use passenger on services like Heroku https://github.com/phusion/passenger-ruby-heroku-demo#readme, just develop in windows and deploy in heroku.

Good lucky.

Answer (score 3):

Phusion Passenger does not support Windows.