# gem install passenger : failed to build gem native extension on Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, passenger

I've tried typing

```
gem install passenger
```

The error I've gotten is as

```
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing passenger:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb 
    C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger4.0.17/lib/phusion_passengerrb:177:in `find_location_configuration_file': undefined method `dir' for nil:NilClass (NoMehodError)

    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.17/lib/phuson_passenger.rb:78:in `locate_directories'
    from extconf.rb:43:in `<main>'
```

Any idea? I'm using ruby 1.9.3

```
   ruby 1.9.3p392 (2013-02-22) [i386-mingw32]
```

Comment: I don't think you can install passenger on Windows - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/999532/passenger-on-windows

Comment: Actually, that *should* have changed in 4.0.17. Meaning that you can install the gem on Windows, although the contents don't actually work. I see that we haven't properly taken the mingw32 version of Ruby in account. I've fixed this in the latest commit.

Comment: what does it mean by contents doesn't work? I want to use passenger as that's what elastic beanstalk is using for rails. Would the latest commit allow me to do that?